# Remove ajax call from regular links with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile I would like to disable the ajax call on links within a specific part of the DOM.

I do not want to put a

```
data-ajax = false
```

every time I don't want to use the jquerymobile ajax.

For example, any link that is a child of 'content':

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="http://externalwebsite.com">External Link</a>
</div>
```

I would like to add the 'data-ajax = false' onto every link that is a child of 'content'

Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to disable the ajax link behaviour from an anchor tag, you can put `rel=external` in the link and the link will load without ajax and your url will then be usual.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

```
<a href="User/somepage" rel="external" />I wont be using ajax for navigation</a>
```

If you want to do this in jQuery for some a tags inside content div, you may try like this

```
$(function(){
  $(".content a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("rel","external");
  });
});
```

Here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/4WEBk/3/

The more Simplified version. (Thanks to [tandu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/tandu) for pointing )

```
$(function(){
  $(".content a").attr("rel","external");
});
```

Comment: This is a slower alternative.  The call to `.each` is unnecessary since the setter version of `.attr` works on a collection.  You could also call `$(".content a").each()` which avoids adding to the symbol table.

Comment: Wouldn't adding `rel="external"` be just as bad as adding `data-ajax=false`?  Good answer, but I think it creates the same requirements that the OP doesn't want.

Comment: @JoshAllen the OP was asking for an easy way to automatically add an attribute to a specific selector .. if he wanted to leave the attributes *off*, he could solve that by doing nothing.

Comment: @JoshAllen: As per jQMobile docs, adding rel will stop the links from being ajaxified. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".content a").attr('data-ajax', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add rel="external" and target="_self" also to make it work.

> Under certain conditions, normal http requests will be used instead of
>   Ajax requests. One case where this is true is when linking to pages on
>   external websites. You can also specify that a normal http request be
>   made through the following link attributes:
>
> - rel=external
> - target (with any value, such as "_blank")